# Google maps reviews

Tags: python-3.x, django

Привет, подскажите есть ли способ отображать более 5-ти reviews из google maps используя следующий код

```
r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=<place_id>&key=<api_key>')
```

И как получить среднюю оценку как например вот тут: http://investigationhotline.org/
P.s По-моему на данном сайте ревьюхи не подтягиваются посредством api.

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? Ваш код слишком общий.

Comment: Да я уже вроде разобрался. Чтобы получить более детальные и полные данные о месте, нужно юзать Google My Business API, а запрос который был выше выдает всего но по чуть-чуть, конкретно интересовали ревьюхи (чтобы вытягивать их все).